# How to run tests in subfolders by using makefile and mocha

Tags: makefile, mocha.js

My structure of the test folder looks like this :

```
<test>
    <test1>
    <test2>
    <test3>
```

Is it possible to write a makefile which execute tests in a single folder  or in some permutation of folders  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it is possible:

```
# I like to allow the user to override the default mocha with whatever
# they want in case they are running an experimental version.
MOCHA?=mocha

# Useful to pass ad hoc parameters to mocha.
MOCHA_PARAMS?=

# To work around the fact that commas are argument separators.
comma:=,

.PHONY: test test%

# Do all the tests.
test:
    $(MOCHA) --recursive $(MOCHA_PARAMS)

# Allows for combining tests in an ad hoc manner.
test%:
        $(MOCHA) $(MOCHA_PARAMS) $(foreach test,$(subst $(comma), ,$(@:test%=%)),test/test$(test))
```

The last target allows you to do things like:

```
make test1 # runs the tests in test/test1 only
make test1,2 # runs the tests in test/test1 and test/test2
make test1,2,3 # runs the tests in test/test1, test/test2, test/test3
make test1,3 # runs the tests in test/test1, and test/test3
```

What happens in the last target is that the target name (e.g. `test1,2`) has the `test` prefix stripped, is split on the commas and then each piece has `test/test` prepended to it.

If you want to test it, copy the code above into a Makefile and just create the `test` directory and any number of subdirectories named `test1`, `test2`, ... `testN` under it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use make at all. Try adding the following to the scripts section of your package.json:

```
"test": "mocha -R spec --recursive",
"test1": "mocha -R spec test/test1",
"test2": "mocha -R spec test/test2",
"test3": "mocha -R spec test/test3",
"test13": "mocha -R spec test/test1 test/test3",
```

Then, you can `npm test` or `npm run test` or `npm run test13`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was

```
test:
  @./node_modules/.bin/mocha -R spec -r should --recursive
cloudApi:
  find $(CURDIR)/test/cloudApi -iname "*.js" | xargs node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha -R spec -r should 
injectors:
  find $(CURDIR)/test/injectors -iname "*.js" | xargs node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha -R spec -r should  

.PHONY: test cloudApi injectors
```

and the execution itself looks like :
mocha test / cloudApi / injectors...